# Grasshopper2 camera doesn't switch off

Tags: ros, camera1394, camera, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The camera1394 driver seems to leave the Point Grey Grasshopper2 (IEEE 1394b version) **ON** after it is stopped (roscore included).

I say it *seems* because the camera case is hot after I stop the driver. Yes, that's how I know it remains **ON**. If you know, by the way, of any other way to check to power state of the camera (or the firewire bus), please, let me know.

With **coriander** the camera case goes to ambient temperature after I exit coriander (actually I press the power **OFF** button before exit), so it seems it's switching the camera off correctly.

Does anybody else experienced a similar problem/behaviour?

How can I fix it? Should I touch the camera1394 (pkg) driver?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12505/grasshopper2-camera-doesn%27t-switch-off/) by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on ROS Answers with karma: 834 on 2012-01-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-02**:
Worth a try. Please let me know if it works for the Grasshopper2.

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-01-02**:
Regarding a fix to power OFF the camera, would it be enough if I add: dc1394_camera_set_power( camera_, DC1394_OFF ) to dev_camera1394.cpp:354 (located in src/nodes of camera1394 pkg)? Is there any side effect?

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-01-02**:
Regarding the way I check the camera power state, I've just realized that the camera LED provides that information. It confirms that the camera is power ON. I'd say it's also in streaming mode. In coriander, when no image is displayed, the LED blinks green. When power OFF it's red/green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've successfully applied the easy fix I mentioned above to power OFF the camera on exit. Now, at least for my Grasshopper2, the LED turns red/green (power OFF state) and the camera cools down.

For more details see this [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5322) and the patch file attached to it.

Here you have the output of the diff command I run to create the patch file

```
--- dev_camera1394.cpp.bak      2012-01-02 20:56:08.306350703 +0000
+++ dev_camera1394.cpp  2012-01-02 21:12:34.778337485 +0000
@@ -350,6 +350,7 @@
     {
       format7_.stop();
       dc1394_capture_stop(camera_);
+      dc1394_camera_set_power(camera_, DC1394_OFF);
       dc1394_camera_free(camera_);
       camera_ = NULL;
     }
```

By the way, I run this command

```
diff -u dev_camera1394.cpp.bak dev_camera1394.cpp > dev_camera1394.cpp.patch
```

---

Originally posted by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) with karma: 834 on 2012-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On shutdown, the `camera1394` driver sets video transmission off, stops capturing frames, and frees the `libdc1394` resources. It currently does not attempt to power off the device.

Although `coriander` documentation says "few cameras support the on/off feature", `camera1394` could support it for those that do. If you think it should, please [open a Trac ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/) for `camera_drivers`. There is time to make that change for the coming Fuerte release.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2